# SQL how do I sum up a has many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, database, orm, relational-database

So I have the following table, I managed to join users and membership tables just fine with a left join however I've been unsuccessful at summing up the individual customers' total.

Here's my code, the one-to-one associations seem to be doing fine however the summing up of the total seems to not display, what am I doing wrong? is there a different way of summing up a one-to-many association?

```
SELECT name, membership.userId as customerId, SUM(sales.total) as Total 
FROM users

LEFT OUTER JOIN membership ON membership.userId = users.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sales ON buyerId = users.id
```

Tables

```
Users table:
id     name     type 
1      John     Customer
2      Adam     Customer
3      Robert   Customer

Membership table:
id     userId 
1      1
2      2
3      3


Sales table:
buyerId  total
1        12
1        20
1        5
2        5
2        10
3        5
3        5
```

Desired output:

```
Sales Report:
Name      CustomerId   Total
John      1            37
Adam      2            15
Robert    3            10
```

Comment: You need a GROUP BY clause too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT name, membership.userId as customerId, SUM(sales.total) as Total 
FROM users

LEFT OUTER JOIN membership ON membership.userId = users.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sales ON buyerId = users.id
GROUP BY name, customerId
```

You need to group by user.